# Linq count products for a specific customer

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-5

hi I have this query that count all the products sold and now I want to change it so it counts the amount of products for a particular customer. Anyone can help me please? Tables= table customer one2many transactions one2many transactionitems many2one product many2one producttype

```
            var query = from product in cse.tblTransactionItems
                        group product by product.tblProduct.Description into g
                        select new { ProductId = g.Key, totalUnitsSold = g.Count() };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider grouping by multiple columns.

```
var query = from product in cse.tblTransactionItems
            group product by new
            {
                product.tblProduct.Description,
                product.tblProduct.Customer // put the customer here.
            } into g
            select new
            {
                Product = g.Key.Description,
                Customer = g.Key.Customer,
                totalUnitsSold = g.Count()
            };
```

This way the `totalUnitsSold` is a total for a specific customer and product.

Note: If your customer is in another table, you'll need to join first. The above simply assumes customer to be part of your existing table.